# Python How to clear screen without clearing user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am trying to make a chat system, but to update the screen, I need to clear it, then print out the messages.
Here is the code I am using, but it also clears the input that is already typed in by the user when the method `clear()` is ran:

```
def receive():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        while True:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM chat"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row[0]+": "+row[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        clear()
```

I am using multiprocessing, and here is where I am trying to take input:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=receive)

p.start()

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    while True:
        ask = input()
        if ask == "cancel()":
            p.terminate()
            clear()
            main()
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "insert into chat (name, message) values (%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (name, ask))
            connection.commit()
```

`clear` is defined as `clear = lambda: os.system('clear')`

Any help as to keep the input from being erased would be appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you alternatively just print the last message? Instead of clearing the screen and printing all of them?

Comment: You probably want to look at some sort of command line ui library like curses for better control over the terminal.

Comment: Use 'clear -x' instead

Answer (score 0):

Use 'clear -x' instead of 'clear' statement